# grep with exclude pattern in shell

Tags: linux, shell, grep

text file has below lines named 'log'

```
--- [n-event-group-3] action
--- [n-event-group-8] action.service
--- [n-event-group-2] essing.service.
--- [n-event-group-10] service.
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-11] ervice
--- [-event-group-15] ervice
--- [-event-group-20] ervice
--- [-event-group-99] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

want to grep lines containing [-event-group-13] and all line which does not have pattern [-event-group-(digits)]

so result needed is

```
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

I tried `grep -vE '-event-group-[^13]' log` but returns lines with

```
[n-event-group-3]
[n-event-group-10]
[n-event-group-11]
[n-event-group-15]
```

as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` better fits your needs here:

```
$ awk '!/-event-group-/{print} /-event-group-13/{print}' file

--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

Comment: awk '!/-event-group-/{print} /-event-group-13/{print}' log1

--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-133] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice



It is retuning '--- [-event-group-133] ervice' as when we added a new line in file

i need exact match

Comment: Hi, this is not a forum :) Ask a new question